# Task continuation was scheduled to non thread-pool thread. Why?

Tags: c#, multithreading, mono, async-await

In my console application I do create my own Thread to implement working queue. Besides I have implemented my own SynchronizationContext for this only thread.

When I await a Task from the Main thread suddenly continuation (the remaining part of my routine) is scheduled on to my working thread what is wrong because I do not expect my thread will be used as a ThreadPool thread for random  tasks.

I am experiencing this behaviour only when running the code with Mono.

Here is a code which reproduces the problem on mono (tested at mac os x and linux system):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        Foo();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    async static void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "{0}: current thread ID={1}; scheduler={2}; context={3};",
            "   Main BEFORE awaiting",
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, 
            TaskScheduler.Current.Id,
            SynchronizationContext.Current != null );
            // MONO Output: Main BEFORE awaiting: current thread ID=1; scheduler=1; context=False;

        WorkQueue queue = new WorkQueue();

        // !!! 
        // I do expect that current context which is null will be captured for continuation.
        // !!!
        await queue.Enqueue();

        // !!!
        // As we can see our custom context was captured to continue with this part of code.
        // 
        Console.WriteLine( "{0}: current thread ID={1}; scheduler={2}; context={3};",
            "   Main AFTER awaiting",
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
            TaskScheduler.Current.Id,
            SynchronizationContext.Current != null );
        // MONO Output: Main AFTER awaiting: current thread ID=4; scheduler=1; context=True;
    }
}

// Custom context which does nothing but enqueues fake tasks to the queue.
//
class WorkQueueSyncContext : SynchronizationContext
{
    readonly WorkQueue queue;

    public WorkQueueSyncContext( WorkQueue queue )
    {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public override void Post( SendOrPostCallback d, object state )
    {
    }

    public override void Send( SendOrPostCallback d, object state )
    {
        queue.Enqueue().Wait();
    }
}

// The queue
//
class WorkQueue
{
    readonly Thread thread;

    class WorkQueueItem
    {
        public TaskCompletionSource<object> Completion
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    BlockingCollection<WorkQueueItem> queue = new BlockingCollection<WorkQueueItem>();


    public WorkQueue()
    {
        thread = new Thread( new ThreadStart( Run ) );
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        // Set ower own SynchronizationContext.
        //
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext( new WorkQueueSyncContext( this ) );

        Console.WriteLine( "{0}: current thread ID={1}; scheduler={2}; context={3};",
            "   WorkQueue START",
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
            TaskScheduler.Current.Id,
            SynchronizationContext.Current != null );
        // MONO Output: current thread ID=4; scheduler=1; context=True;

        // Working loop.
        //
        while ( true )
        {
            WorkQueueItem item = queue.Take();

            Console.WriteLine( "{0}: current thread ID={1}; scheduler={2}; context={3};",
                "   WorkQueue DOING TASK",
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                TaskScheduler.Current.Id,
                SynchronizationContext.Current != null );
            // MONO Output: current thread ID=4; scheduler=1; context=True;

            // Completed the task :)
            //
            item.Completion.SetResult( true );
        }
    }

    public Task<object> Enqueue()
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<object> completion = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        queue.Add( new WorkQueueItem() { Completion = completion } );
        return completion.Task;
    }
}
```

So, here is MONO output:

```
   Main BEFORE awaiting: current thread ID=1; scheduler=1; context=False;
   WorkQueue START: current thread ID=3; scheduler=1; context=True;
   WorkQueue DOING TASK: current thread ID=3; scheduler=1; context=True;
   Main AFTER awaiting: current thread ID=3; scheduler=1; context=True;
```

And this is Windows output:

```
   Main BEFORE awaiting: current thread ID=10; scheduler=1; context=False;
   WorkQueue START: current thread ID=11; scheduler=1; context=True;
   WorkQueue DOING TASK: current thread ID=11; scheduler=1; context=True;
   Main AFTER awaiting: current thread ID=6; scheduler=1; context=False;
```

Please note (the last line) how context capturing differs.

EDIT:

Is not reproducible with Mono 3.4.0, so seems to be a bug in older version (at least 3.2.6);

Comment: Does Mono have `ConfigureAwait`?

Comment: Where are you calling `Foo`?  What is the main loop of `Run` doing?  There is simply too much missing information to know what's going on here.

Comment: >> Does Mono have ConfigureAwait? - Yes it has

Comment: >> Where are you calling Foo? -- from the main default thread where Main() resides.

Comment: @AntonPetrov Edit the code sample to actually show us what's going on.  Your code sample should be able to replicate the problem, currently it cannot; not even close.

Comment: @Servy - okay. It will take some time.

Comment: @Servy - done. Here is working example short as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've found a bug in Mono runtime. The continuation after `await` should not be happening on a thread with a different synchronization context from that captured by `TaskAwaiter`, at the point of `await`.

The following scenarios are possible:

1. Both the original thread and the completion thread have *the same* synchronization context. The continuation may be inlined (executed synchronously on the completion thread).
2. Both the original thread and the completion thread have no synchronization context (`SynchronizationContext.Current == null`). The continuation still may be inlined.
3. In any other combination, the continuation must not be inlined.

By "may be inlined" I mean it is not required or guaranteed to be so (it still might be scheduled using `TaskScheduler.Current` or `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` for asynchronous execution). Nevertheless, under the current Microsoft's implementation of TPL, it does get inlined for conditions #1 and #2.

However, **for #3 it must not be inlined**, this is dictated by common sense. So feel free to report a bug to Xamarin. Try the most recent Mono build first to see if the problem is still there.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me it could be a bug :) I was testing with mono 3.2.6, but 3.4.0 looks to be okay.