# Task continuation was not scheduled on thread-pool thread

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task, continuations

I was reading about SynchronizationContext and its use with the async/await methods ([link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx)). From my understanding, in a Console application where the SynchronizationContext is null, the continuation of an awaited method (Task) will be scheduled with the default scheduler which would be the ThreadPool.

But if I run this console app, you'll see from the output that the the continuation is run on the worker thread that I created:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MainThreadId=" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Method1().ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("After Method1. ThreadId=" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        });

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static async Task Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method1 => Entered. ThreadId=" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        TaskCompletionSource<bool> completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Method1 => Started new thread. ThreadId=" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            completionSource.SetResult(true);
        });

        thread.Start();

        await completionSource.Task;

        Console.WriteLine("Method1 => After WorkerThread. ThreadId=" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```cs
MainThreadId=10
Method1 => Entered. ThreadId=10
Method1 => Started new thread. ThreadId=11
Method1 => After WorkerThread. ThreadId=11
After Method1. ThreadId=12
```

As you can see, "After WorkerThread" was outputted on the same thread as my workerthread, but not on the threadpool.

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22965202/task-continuation-was-scheduled-to-non-thread-pool-thread-why) but the guy was using Mono and they were saying that this was a bug. On my side, I built this code with in Visual Studio and ran it under Windows 7 and .Net 4.5.2 installed on my machine.

Could someone please explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of an [implementation detail that I documented on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html): the continuation created by `await` is scheduled using the `ExecuteSynchronously` flag. In that case, when it is time to fire the continuation (i.e., in the `TaskCompletionSource<T>.SetResult` call on the worker thread), the default scheduler first attempts to determine whether it can run on the current thread.

[Since the worker thread has no `TaskScheduler` that will reject executing the task synchronously](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/07/10265067.aspx), the `ExecuteSynchronously` flag will [cause the thread pool task scheduler to just execute the task synchronously](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.cs,bfd287ca768974fd,references) (i.e., on the calling thread).

Comment: Good catch! So this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx?PageIndex=2#comments) is wrong by saying that "When the Task being awaited completes, a continuation will run the remainder of the asynchronous method. If the captured SynchronizationContext was null, then RestOfMethod() will be executed in the original TaskScheduler (which is often TaskScheduler.Default, meaning the ThreadPool)"?

Comment: @Absolom: Technically, it is being executed in the thread pool task scheduler. The odd behavior is due to the thread pool task scheduler deciding that your thread is part of its context.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but could you explain why in my example the "After Method1" is scheduled by the thread pool task scheduler and is actually run on the thread pool and not on the same thread. Why isn't it  the same behaviour for both the Async and the Task?

Comment: @Absolom: The manual `ContinueWith` call does not specify `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously`.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll buy your book to help me understand all these subtleties :)

Comment: @Absolom: Actually, my book doesn't go into the corner cases. It's more of an introduction to TPL, async, Dataflow, and Rx, and how they all can fit together.